# Failed 18.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, login, settings, dock

Upgraded 16.04 to 18.04, login screen does not come up, also, DOCK is missing from settings menu.  No, uncommenting GDM3 custom.config WaylandEnable=false does not work.

Comment: Uninstalling gdm3 and installing lightdm sort of worked, but reboot is still very slow and login page buggy....have to move mouse left to get user names to display, and screen is jerky.

Comment: Lightdm brought back the DOCK in settings and also defaulted to locking taskbar on the left - much nicer.